# Java junit.framework.AssertionFailedError error

Tags: java

```
currentCapacity = queue.getCapacityLeft();

if(currentCapacity == queue.getCapacityLeft()) System.out.println("yes");

assertTrue( "Should have resized array",currentCapacity < queue.getCapacityLeft() );
```

These two have 2 different displays: the first one displays "yes" which means current capacity is equal to queue.getCapacityLeft, but the second one is displayed too.

This is my method:

```
public int getCapacityLeft() { return 0; }
```

Why do I have this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assertTrue method as specified in the [javadoc](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.8/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) indicates that this method:

> Asserts that a condition is true. If it isn't it throws an AssertionError with the given message.

because the condition `currentCapacity < queue.getCapacityLeft()` is false it throws the `AssertionError` and prints the message "Should have resized array" that is why you see the this message displayed too.

Comment: I thought that condition writes "Should have resized array" if the condition was true. Can you explain to me? Because basically I am comparing 0 with 0 and it returns as true with that message and I am confused

Comment: Yes sure the condition for the assert sentence use the lower than operator ‘<‘ instead the equals operator ‘==‘ as you use in the first sentence, so if you want the assert evaluated to true you have to change the operator from ‘<‘ to ‘==‘ beacause 0 < 0 is false